Given $C \sim \text{Cauchy}$, use Box-Muller to demonstrate that $C - 1/C \sim 2C$
Question: the Cauchy distribution is defined as the ratio of two iid random variables with a normal distribution. Letting $C \sim \text{Cauchy}$, use the Box-Muller representation of normal variables to show that $C - 1/C \sim 2C$.
Attempt: Let $C = Z_1/Z_2$ where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are iid random variables with a standard normal distribution. Using the Box-Muller representation, we have $Z_1 = \sqrt{-2\ln U_2}\cos(2\pi U_1)$ and $Z_2 = \sqrt{-2\ln U_2}\sin(2\pi U_1)$, where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are iid uniform, so
\begin{gather*}
C = \frac{\cos(2\pi U_2)}{\sin(2\pi U_2)}.
\end{gather*}
At this point, I get stuck. I've tried to rewrite $C - 1/C$ using the representation above, i.e.,
\begin{gather*}
C - 1/C  = \frac{\cos^2(2\pi U_2) - \sin^2(2\pi U_2)}{\sin(2\pi U_2)\cos(2\pi U_2)} = \frac{\cos(2\pi U_2)}{\sin(2\pi U_2)} - \tan(2\pi U_2)
\end{gather*}
Are there any trigonometric identities I could use to rewriting any of the expressions above to resemble something closer to a representation of $2C$? Alternatively, since $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ were chosen arbitrarily as the numerator/denominator of $C$, could I use the fact that $1/C \sim \text{Cauchy}$ to get anywhere?
Update: using the trig identity given as a hint by Winther, we have
\begin{gather*}
C - 1/C   = \frac{\cos(2\pi U_2)}{\sin(2\pi U_2)} - \tan(2\pi U_2) = 2\frac{\cos(2\pi U_2)}{\sin(2\pi U_2)} = 2C
\end{gather*}

The identity $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} - \tan(x) = 2\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}$ might be useful here.

Thanks @Winther!

@Winther, as someone else pointed out, I made a mistake as the identity you gave me gives me $C - 1/C = 2\cos(4\pi U_2)/\sin(4\pi U_2)$. I need to show that this equals $2\cos(2\pi U_2)/\sin(2\pi U_2)$. It should be easy since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are periodic functions, but I'm still having difficulty proving this is the case. Any tips? Thanks!
